# How to copy text with font information as well?

Tags: windows, macos, browser, php, fonts

I wonder, how to copying text with font information? Copying any text from the website below and paste to any document have the exact font style! What is the mechanism behind it?

> https://coolfont.org/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

₵ØØⱠ₣Ø₦₮.ØⱤ₲
c҉o҉o҉l҉f҉o҉n҉t҉.o҉r҉g҉
.
☾⊙⊙↳Ϝ⊙♫☂.⊙☈❡

On Mac, just copy/paste it. No special trickery required.

It's presumably dependant on whether your computer recognises &/or already contains the glyphs.

btw, they're not "fonts" as such, they're unicode glyphs.
A glyph is a 'shape'… the letter A is a glyph, just the same as  is a glyph [albeit one I don't know the meaning of].
You need to already have a font in your machine that can display the glyph, but it's told to "use that font" simply by being told to print a given glyph [shape]. Your OS then does the rest, figuring out if it has a font containing that glyph to display on your screen.

To take one character from that list as an example. Your computer is told to print the glyph Unicode: U+263E It has a look around & finds that's a 'Last Quarter Moon' so it prints ☾
There was no 'font' instruction sent to it, it figured that out for itself simply from the unicode data U+263E.

Just in case anyone doesn't have the glyphs to see my opening 4 lines, here it is as a simple screen-cap of the section. Different OSes, Browsers, etc may display these slightly differently, depending on precisely which fonts are called by the OS to display them.

[image]